# Query multiple, nested Relationships in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to build a simple news feed for posts in Laravel with Eloquent.

I basically want to retrieve all **Posts**...

- where I am author
- where people I follow are author (followable)
- where people I follow have commented on
- where people with same field_id are author
- where poeple with same school_id are author

in one query.

As I never worked intensivly with joined/combined SQL queries, any help on this is greatly appreciated!

### My Tables

`users` table

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
```

`posts` table

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | author_id | author_type |
|----|-----------|-------------|
|    | users.id  | 'App\User'  |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

`comments` table

```
+----+----------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | commentable_id | commentable_type | author_id | author_type |
|----|----------------|------------------|-----------|-------------|
|    | posts.id       | 'App\Post'       | users.id  | 'App\User'  |
+----+----------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

`schoolables` table

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | school_id | field_id |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

`followables` table

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| follower_id | follower_type | followable_id | followable_type |
|-------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------|
| users.id    | 'App\User'    | users.id      | 'App\User'      |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

### My Models

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
     */
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Post::class, 'author')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'author')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function schoolables()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Schoolable::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function following()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Followable::class, 'follower');
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is your code for your attempt? Or are you just hoping someone will write the entire thing for you?

Comment: @pitchinnate I don't hope for anything, I simply want to learn how to build such queries or gather some more resources for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use left joins for this query, but it would become a complex thing, because you have to make all the joins with leftJoins and then a nested orWhere clause on all the

```
$posts = Post::leftJoin('..', '..', '=', '..')
  ->where(function($query){
    $query->where('author_id', Auth::user()->id); // being the author
  })->orWhere(function($query){
    // second clause...
  })->orWhere(function($query){
    // third clause...
  .....
  })->get();
```

I don't think this will be manageable, so I would advice using UNIONS, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions

So it would be something like..

```
$written = Auth::user()->posts();
$following = Auth::user()->following()->posts();
```

After getting the different queries, without getting the results, you can unite them..

```
$posts = $written->union($following)->get();
```

Hopefully this will direct you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you want to retrieve all posts where any of the 5 conditions above apply. The trick to writing such queries is to break them up into smaller, more manageable pieces.

```
$query = Post::query();
```

So let's say you are `$me`.

The ids of users you are following can be obtained with

```
$followingUserIds = $me
    ->following()
    ->where('followable_type', User::class)
    ->lists('followable_id');
```

The ids of users in the same fields as you can be obtained with

```
$myFieldIds = $me->schoolables()->lists('field_id');
$sharedFieldUserIds = Schoolable::whereIn('field_id', $myFieldIds)->lists('user_id');
```

Similarly, users in the same school as you can be obtained with

```
$mySchoolIds = $me->schoolables()->lists('school_id');
$sharedSchoolUserIds = Schoolable::whereIn('school_id', $mySchoolIds)->lists('user_id');
```

Let's define each of those conditions:

**Where I am author**

```
$query->where(function($inner) use ($me) {
    $inner->where('posts.author_type', User::class);
    $inner->where('posts.author_id', $me->id);
});
```

**Where people I follow are author (followable)**

```
$query->orWhere(function($inner) use ($followingUserIds) {
    $inner->where('posts.author_type', User::class);
    $inner->whereIn('posts.author_id', $followingUserIds);
});
```

**where people I follow have commented on**
This one is actually slightly tricky: we need to use the `->whereHas` construct, which finds posts with at least 1 comment matching the subquery.

```
$query->orWhereHas('comments', function($subquery) use ($followingUserIds) {
    $subquery->where('comments.author_type', User::class);
    $subquery->whereIn('comments.author_id', $followingUserIds);
});
```

The remaining two are simple.

**where people with same field_id are author**

```
$query->orWhere(function($inner) use ($sharedFieldUserIds) {
    $inner->where('posts.author_type', User::class);
    $inner->whereIn('posts.author_id', $sharedFieldUserIds);
});
```

and you can see where this is going

**where poeple with same school_id are author**

```
$query->orWhere(function($inner) use ($sharedSchoolUserIds) {
    $inner->where('posts.author_type', User::class);
    $inner->whereIn('posts.author_id', $sharedSchoolUserIds);
});
```

To get the matching posts, you just need to do

```
$posts = $query->get();
```

While constructing the query from scratch works in this particular case, it will create a fairly brittle structure if your requirements ever change. For added flexibility, you probably want to build [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) on the `Post` and `Comments` models for each of those components. That will mean that you only need to figure out one time what it means for a post to be authored by someone a user follows, then you could simply do `Post::authoredBySomeoneFollowedByUser($me)` to get the collection of posts authored by someone you follow.